# javascript indexOf multi-dimensional array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array of objects example:

```
var myVar = new Array();
    myVar.push({'abc':'123','def':'456'});
    myVar.push({'ghi':'789','jkl':'012'});
```

and I would like to find the indexOf for the array level of a given object by property/value.

```
alert(myVar.indexOf('ghi'));
```

does not appear to be the route of action to find it, and I think I understand why, but figuring out how to get the index of the array of the object that has the property of `ghi` has got me stumped, and open for idea's.

Comment: The elements of your array are objects--not strings, so no string is ever going to be found in your array.

Comment: don't use `new Array()`. Use `[]`. In your case, even `[{...},{...}]`.

Comment: the array is built dynamically.. I find the occasional issue using myVar.push when initially defining my array with just `[]` and the objects adding to the array over time coule be simply just one or 2 or a hundred, but its over the course of a users interaction. So defining in early with `[{..}, {..}]` doesn't work for the overall cause. Unfortunately I am building on top of an existing system so, I have to work with what I got, as they won't allocate time for a rewrite of a lot of things, so stuck with what I got, and trying to find means of working with that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var findIndex=function(key,arr) {
    for(var i=0, j=arr.length; i<j; i++) {
        if(arr[i].hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
};
var index=findIndex('ghi',myVar);
```

**Edit**
Jan made an important point: remember to expect integers no lower than `0` for successful finds even though `0` evaluates to `false` since it's a valid index. `-1` means your key wasn't found.

Comment: note that it returns `undefined` if the element is not found. If you want `-1` instead, just add an explicit return statement at the end.

Comment: +1, but why a function expression instead of a declaration?

Comment: Just my style :) I'm used to coding functions as properties of other objects. And since functions are first-class objects in JavaScript it makes more sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>**[Working FIDDLE Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mojtaba/7Hgfc/2/)**</kbd>

Write a function for it, like this:

```
function findIndex(arr, key) {
    for (var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) {
        if (arr[i].hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            return i;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

And the result:

```
findIndex(myVar, 'ghi');
// 1

findIndex(myVar, 'def');
// 0
```

And it will return `-1` if nothing found:

```
findIndex(myVar, 'non');
// -1
```

Comment: That `if (l)` is kinda pointless here. If `l` is zero, the iteration condition will handle the fact.

Comment: @JanDvorak EXACTLY, I've correct it ;)

Comment: +1, but instead of `j = i; break;` just `return i;` will do. And remove the outer *if* per Jan's comment.

Comment: get inspired by [panpier's code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16661304/499214) ;-)

Comment: @RobG YES, you are right, I've changed it ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
Array.prototype.findIndexOf = function(prop) {
    var i = -1;
    this.forEach(function(elem, index) {
        if (prop in elem) {
            i = index;
            return false;
        }
    })
    return i;
}

console.log(myVar.findIndexOf('property'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZUHPF/

Comment: `Array.prototype.index = ` -- I don't recommend extending the classes you don't own. You could namespace-collide with some other developer, a library, a future version of ecmascript...

Comment: I was referring to the idea of extending core classes, not to the specific name chosen.

Comment: One would hope one would be aware of what other libraries, developers are doing. There should be no such what-ifs.

Comment: @squint in theory, you're right. In practice, I don't recommend that anyways.

Comment: @JanDvorak: With all due respect, being aware of ones coding environment shouldn't be approached as a theory. IMO, it should be a standard practice, and a first priority. Your point about future ECMAScript additions is certainly valid, but those are *very* slow moving, are few and far between, and can be seen years in advance.

Comment: @squint note that it's not _my_ invention to not do that. See which approach jQuery and underscore.js took. Another point is that when you're extending core classes, there's no way to quickly identify where you should look for documentation. Whether it's MDN, prototype.js documentation or your own code base.

Comment: @JanDvorak: Those are public libraries. That's a very different concern from project code. There's no reason to apply the concerns of such a library to all situations. That said, I checked the most recent ES6 draft, and there's an `Array.prototype` extension that offers similar functionality, so best approach would be to test for that method, and add it. That way the code is future-proof. ***15.4.3.24 Array.prototype.findIndex ( predicate , thisArg = undefined )***

Comment: @squint note, however, it's still a draft. If that method spec changes, you need to follow.

Comment: @JanDvorak: Yes, I did note that... in my comment. ;-) Seems unlikely that the semantics of such a simple operation would change much or at all, but it is a valid concern. One could implement under a modified name, perhaps with a leading underscore, and then do a quick find/replace as desired when the spec is finalized.

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate over the array.  `.indexOf` is not going to work any way you slice it.

```
myVar.forEach(function (elem, idx) {
    if (elem.hasOwnProperty('ghi')) {
        console.log(idx);
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/uaPVP/

Better methods can probably be used depending upon what you want to do with the index specifically, but this should at least give you an idea.

Comment: Since he probably wants to use the index further, a functional-style iteration is probably a burden here.

Comment: @JanDvorak why?  It really depends on specifics (is he looking for the index or the element, and a single element or possibly multiple elements)?

Comment: Should also stop searching once the property is found.

Comment: This basically runs the code for every element with that property.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing the objects in an array you can put them in a parent object where each object is a property on the parent object. This will allow you to get objects by a key like you are trying to do.

```
var myObject = {
    abc: {'abc':'123','def':'456'},
    ghi: {'ghi':'789','jkl':'012'}
}
```

Now you can access the objects by key instead of looping over each item in an array:

```
var objectByKey = myObject['ghi']; // grab object by property name like this
```

Comment: `myObject` would have to have four elements in this case, not two. Once for each key. The idea is good, however.

Comment: I'm assuming this is just bogus data so I figured a simple example would suffice.